# How to display div element always when checkbox is not marked

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have checkboxes and when I start maring them, a div appears. How can I make the div to be visible always and not only when a checkbox is marked?

Live example: https://www.advokatami.bg/poruchki/bundle/ -> I am talking about the div where Checkboxes total and Total price appear.

Here is the javascript I think is responsible for show/hide of the element: https://codeshare.io/HxNeQ

Comment: It is already visible but doesn't have a content!

Comment: please share some code directly into the question

Comment: You are dynamically adding the elements, but the div itself is not hidden. Why anyway do you want that behavior?

Comment: The code is probably 300 lines, I thought codeshare will be better.
@RohitKishore - how can I see it is visible through inspect element?

Comment: @Gorna-Bania search for `product-addons-total` in inspector!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to achieve your goal you need to proceed following 2 steps :

1 - Show the content you want on the div on page ready doing so at the beginning of the js :

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function($) {
//shows the cart content on page ready.
var html = '<dl class="product-addon-totals">
                <dt>Checkboxes total:</dt>
                    <dd><strong><span class="amount">0 лв.</span></strong></dd>
                <dt>Total price:</dt>
                    <dd><strong><span class="amount">0 лв.</span></strong></dd>
            </dl>';

$.("#product-addons-total").html(html);
```

Then, the second step is to make the costs equal to 0 when the cart is emptied, instead of just removing the whole content of the div. To achieve this you need to find in the js the call to the function `empty()` on lines `303` and `307` and replace these by the following lines of code :

```
var html = '<dl class="product-addon-totals">
                    <dt>Checkboxes total:</dt>
                        <dd><strong><span class="amount">0 лв.</span></strong></dd>
                    <dt>Total price:</dt>
                        <dd><strong><span class="amount">0 лв.</span></strong></dd>
                </dl>';

    $.("#product-addons-total").html(html);
```

There is, of course cleaner ways to do it which i'll let you code but this should solve your issue already. ;)

Answer (score 2):

The div you're talking about gets appended when a checkbox is checked from line 208 of the code you provided:

```
var html = '<dl class="product-addon-totals"><dt>' + woocommerce_addons_params.i18n_addon_total + '</dt><dd><strong><span class="amount">' + formatted_addon_total + '</span></strong></dd>';
```

so you'll have to add the div markup with the checkbox total to your static html and only update the price when a checkbox is checked by targeting the the element span.amount

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" /> <br />    
<div class ='detail_check show'> detail area<div>


<style>
.show {
  display:block;
}
.hide {
display:none;
}

</style>

$(document).ready(function() {

$('#checkbox').change(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('.detail_check')removeClass('show);
        $('.detail_check')addClass('hide);
    } else {
        $('.detail_check')removeClass('hide);
        $('.detail_check')addClass('show);
    }      
});
```

});

you can do with simple  jave script & css code

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best approach for your code, but it's nice to see you can also do this kind of stuff with only css.

The `+` selector checks for a `span` directly next/under an `input` of `type="checkbox"`.

The `:checked` selects only a checked element.

```css
input[type="checkbox"] + span { display: none; }
input:checked + span { display: inline; }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"><span>Label</span>
```